# Can't mass-assign protected attributes with has_many association and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is EXTREMELY bizarre.  I'm upgrading a Rails 2.3.12 app and running into this same problem over and over again.  I'm stumped and nothing else out there seems to touch on it.

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :logs, :class_name => 'UserLog'
end
```

and

```
class UserLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :site_id, :controller, :action, :url, :session

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

then in another controller I'm doing this:

```
def log_user_activity
   @current_user.logs.create(:site_id => @site.id, :controller => params[:controller],
   :action => params[:action], :url => request.path,
   :session => request.session_options[:id]) if @current_user
end
```

as you can see, it's pretty straightforward but when I call log_user_activity I'm getting this:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: site_id, controller, action, url, session
```

HOWEVER, if I change all my creates or builds to this:

```
def log_user_activity
   log = @current_user.logs.new
   log.site_id = @site.id
   log.controller = params[:controller]
   log.action = params[:action]
   log.url = request.path
   log.session = request.session_options[:id]
   log.save
end
```

then it works fine!?

Has anyone seen this?  Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In class UserLog, add the following:

```
attr_accessible :site_id, :controller, :action, :url, :session
```

The reason you have to use `attr_accessible` is most likely because you are utilizing a plugin that is relying on this being present for a model. It has happened to all of us and is a royal pita)

Once `attr_accessible` is designated for a class, then any attribute that is not specified as 'accessible' will not be allowed to be updated.

Comment: No.. 'attr_accessor' is present.. but not 'attr_accessible'.. 2 different things.. one is ruby, the other rails specific   http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class

Comment: Is it really that much of a "pita" if it means that the attributes for your site are now better protected? This feature, although tiresome to implement, is actually quite useful in the end.

Comment: ok - I believe you are correct.  So basically I use attr_accessible for any existing columns in the database and for any dynamic attributes, such as password_confirmation in a users model, I would FIRST use attr_accessor and then attr_accessible on that column, correct?

Comment: The order of the declarations doesn't matter.. The feature of 'attr_accessible' is due to change in Rails 4 so prepare to learn again soon.. :)